# How to write an array for readings from a sensor?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a sensor that reads distances, could be 1 reading could be 50, since there is an if statement that might break the readings. The distance-measuring part of the code looks like this:

```
distance=mdev.getSonic()
Distance_measured = "%.2f" %distance
print(Distance_measured)
```

(mdev is a method provided by the manufacturers of the car to control speeds, angles, and LED lights)

I need an array that can take the last 5 (for example) readings from the sensor, from which I am able to get an average later on.

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate the question? maybe add examples for inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a list like a fifo queue.
Use append to add to the end of the queue and use pop(0) to remove and element from the front.

Answer (score 0):

```
def store():
    distance=mdev.getSonic()
    Distance_measured = "%.2f" %distance
    distancelist = []
    if len(distancelist)==5:
       distancelist.pop(0)
       distancelist.append(Distance_measured)
    else:
       distancelist.append(Distance_measured)
    distance_avg = sum(distancelist)/len(distancelist)
    return Distance_measured,distance_avg
distance, distance_avg = store()
print(distance)
print(distance_avg)
```

Comment: Can you add a little clarification to your answer?

Comment: I am only getting 2 values ( not 5)  and the average is just the last number, not actually and average.

Comment: Interesting... I am only getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`.

Comment: you can typecast the Distance_measured into float before appending distancelist.append(float(Distance_measured)).